# How to implement collection view like this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to implement collectionview which have functionality when I click on plus cell a new cell will be added and when I click on cross icon cell will be removed and plus cell needs to be moved to the removed cell position,here I am attaching design for reference

[design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr3Ny.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not here to implement whole functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate cell layouts for this design.
In the function that returns the number of items in your `UICollectionView`, simply add one for the last cell.
For object 0..n (where n is the number of data objects in your collection) you then return your custom data cell. For object n+1, you return the cell layout for the "New Item Cell".

You should tak a look at the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol.

[collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618058-collectionview)

[UICollectionViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource)